# How to change cakephp selection field after bake relational table ?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two table users and Areas.Areas has a relation with users.So I have add users_id in Areas table.After bake I get the output fine.But here in areas add form user field is showing users_id in select box.Here I want to show users_name.How can I change it?

Here is the model code

```
MadAreas' => array(
            'className' => 'MadAreas',
            'foreignKey' => 'users_id'
)
```

In controller

```
$madAreas = $this->MadArea->Users->find('list');
```

In add.ctp

```
 echo $this->Form->input('users_id',array( 'label' => false, 'class'=>'form-control' ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the fields you want in your find statement:

```
$madAreas = $this->MadArea->Users->find('list', array(
                                                'fields' => array('id','username')
                                                )
                                       );
```

Changing the `$displayField` in the model as mentioned in @mponos-george's answer should do it anyways, just make sure you clear your Cache files after changing the model value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the display field in your User model

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield

Comment: I have used public $displayField = 'username'; But no any change.

Comment: change this `$madAreas = $this->MadArea->Users->find('list');` to `$users = $this->MadArea->Users->find('list');`

Comment: This is also wrong `echo $this->Form->input('users_id',array( 'label' => false, 'class'=>'form-control' ));` the correct way is  `echo $this->Form->input('user_id',array( 'label' => false, 'class'=>'form-control' ));` with no plural

Comment: I think there should be a condition to apply.Here I am able to see id, that's means it is find id list.I have to assign that find list by name.I have logic but don't know where to apply.

Comment: Try specifying the fields you want in your find: 

``$madAreas = $this->MadArea->Users->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','username')));``

The ``$displayField`` should have done it anyways so it might be your model cache. Clear all your cache files and try again it should probably work

Comment: Yes it is working @ Ayman
Thank a lot.I want to take it ans if you give it as a ans.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the data in your controller before rendering the view?

```
$this->Set(compact('madAreas'));
```